# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

I obtained the case notes for my Great Great Grandmother (Lunacy Asylum). I am slowly working through the text and here is a sentence I am not fully sure about:

[image: Case Notes Extract]

At the moment I have:

> Neuralgia & Deb???? No domestic trouble or mental anxiety. Moral - ????

There are a couple of words that are not clear to me. The first looks like Delulity but this is not a valid English word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Neuralgia & Debility. No domestic trouble or mental anxiety. Moral [possibly &]
>   abstemious.

Debility is physical weakness.
Abstemious means she was moderate in her habits (not a heavy drinker or glutton, for example)

Comment: I have a few more case note queries now that I have completed the 3 page transcript. Should I raise one question per query?

Comment: I would include them in a single query for context.

Comment: Ok. I will look at that tomorrow then. Thanks.

Comment: I think they would be best asked as one query per question but make sure to include links to any earlier questions in the series to provide any context that may be necessary.