# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

This is a continuation of [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes extract?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882) where I made a request for deciphering phrases on my Great Great Grandmothers case notes.

[image: Case notes extract 2a]

[image: Case notes extract 2b]

> Slept 11 hours last night. Takes nourishment well. Is melancholic, agitated and deluded. Snatches **???** at the nurses. Thinks she is going to be **???** to death. Implores me to spare her life and she says she has not killed anyone. Says she is troubled about her soul and though she has brought up her children well she has never had real true inward religion herself. **???** I am and **???** cannot tell the name of this place. Says she has been here a week. Admits that when she came here, she was "not steady enough and kicked about so".

Comment: I think “bite sized” questions here would be more like one extract per question. You can always link to earlier questions in the series for context. I’ve done a similar series of questions when transcribing the 1873 diary of my 3rd great grandfather Thomas Hitchcox here.

Comment: Some of us are splitters and others are lumpers. My preference is “one question per question” on every Stack Exchange site. When we split we risk context being lost. When we lump we risk potential answerers not answering any bits until they think they can answer all bits, and we also risk close votes for too broad. No matter how you structure them, I encourage you to ask your transcription questions.

Comment: See how the rest of the community reacts to this one because I am only one opinion. I think you’ll find you can increase rep and unlock site privileges more quickly by splitting.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have split so please remove comments

Comment: I've raised a meta-question https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3440/6485 so will clean up my comment trail here now @PolyGeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extract appears to read:

> Slept 11 hours last night. Takes nourishment well. Is melancholic, agitated and deluded. Snatches **impulsively** at the nurses. Thinks she is going to be **put** to death. Implores me to spare her life and she says she has not killed anyone. Says she is troubled about her soul and though she has brought up her children well she has never had real true inward religion herself. **Knows** I am a **doctor** cannot tell the name of this place. Says she has been here a week. Admits that when she came here, she was "not steady enough and kicked about so".