# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

This is a continuation of:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes extract?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes - Extract 2](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)

Where I made a request for deciphering phrases on my Great Great Grandmothers case notes.

[image: Case notes extract 3]

> Seems weaker. Brandy resumed last evening. Slept only 1 hour last night **???** Paraldehyde.
>
> Still restless and noisy. Pleading for her life to be spared. Requires Paraldehyde nightly. Slept 10 hours last night after Paraldehyde **???**.

Comment: That last one may be a specific medical abbreviation. I found something very similar on [page 11](https://digital.nls.uk/indiapapers/browse/archive/83973259?mode=transcription) of a  _Report on the working of the Ranchi Indian Mental Hospital, Kanke, in Bihar and Orissa_

Comment: the missing word is despite; the abbreviation is probably a measure (volume/mass/number) and a note on the application, e.g. "3 i V" could mean 3ml (or whatever measure) intravenously. O for orally, a for aspiration (gaseous) etc.
You'll hopefully put the whole thing online if is transcribed fully? Together with pictures of the text and some context that would be very interesting.

Comment: @loonquawl At the moment I only have the digital images in my private Ancestry tree of the three pages. They make for interesting reading. I am not home yet and need to collate the answers provided so far and ask my additional queries. Everyone has been most helpful.

Comment: Note https://forum.antiquebottles-glass.com/discussion/121/bottles-marked-with-3iv-and-duraglas for another interpretation of 3iV : 4 ounces in pharma-speak.

Comment: I suspect the last one is probably the abbreviation for a pharmacological [dram](http://pkperfumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Apothecary-Weights-and-Measurements-Tutorial-rev6-12.pdf), (1⁄8 of an apothecary's ounce), followed by an 'i' indicating the quantity 1 (i.e. "1 dram"), followed by another abbreviation (it seems unlikely that it's a 'v', since it doesn't match the form of the letter 'v' elsewhere in the extract), which may indicate the method of administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems weaker. Brandy resumed last evening. Slept only 1 hour last night **despite** Paraldehyde.
>
> Still restless and noisy. Pleading for her life to be spared. Requires Paraldehyde nightly. Slept 10 hours last night after Paraldehyde **ℨi (?)**.

---

The final 'word' looks to be the abbreviation for a pharmacological [dram](http://pkperfumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Apothecary-Weights-and-Measurements-Tutorial-rev6-12.pdf) (**ℨ**), (1⁄8 of an apothecary's ounce), followed by an '**i**' indicating the quantity 1 (i.e. "1 dram"), followed by another abbreviation.

It is possible that the last letter is a 'v', making the final word **ℨiv**, or "4 drams".  However, this seems unlikely since the symbol doesn't match the form of the letter 'v' as it appears elsewhere in the extract.  It is possible it may be a symbol to indicate the method of administration.

---

As the Wikipedia article notes, [Paraldehyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraldehyde#As_a_hypnotic/sedative)

> "... was regularly given at bedtime in psychiatric hospitals and geriatric wards up to the 1970s."

Although Paraldehyde could be (and still is) given *per rectum* as an [enema](https://www.gosh.nhs.uk/medical-information-0/medicines-information/paraldehyde-and-olive-oil-enema), a dose of 1 dram seems much less than suggested doses I have found while searching (see, for example the 1938 [Analytical Cyclopedia Practical Medicine](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.78609/page/n1)).  It seems more likely in this case that the medicine was administered orally, where a dose in the range ½ - 2 drams before bed seems to have been quite common.

---

If the last symbol does represent the method of administration, I suppose it is possible - with the eye of faith - to read

[image: unknown symbol]

as either as stylised version of "Po" to mean *Per or* (oral administration) or similarly as a stylised version of"Pr" *Per rectum* to mean a rectal enema.  (Personally, I don't find either reading particularly convincing, but it's worth mentioning.)

In any event, I haven't been able to find that symbol listed in any (more-or-less) contemporary medical texts.

---

As a next step, I would check to see if the same symbol / letter appears elsewhere in the document, in which case the context might give you a clue as to its meaning.

Comment: Thanks. One think to bear in mind is that this document has notes from different nurses but in these instances they are the same person I think. I will look for other instance. If found should I attach to this question?

Comment: Notice that at the end of the entry for Nov 15 there is also some text. This looks similar. See? I think the last letter is actually cut off due to the binding. But can you see it in the image? We have omitted it from our text.

Comment: I dd see the Nov 15 entry.  It appears to be in pretty much the same context as the Nov 19 entry, which does suggest that the symbol/letter is intentional, but doesn't actually get us any nearer its meaning.