# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

This is a continuation of

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes extract?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes - Extract 2](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes - Extract 3](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)

Where I made a request for deciphering phrases on my Great Great Grandmothers case notes.

[image: Case notes extract 4]

> Got out through window of **???** section. And over 7 ward **??? ??? ???** onto the cricket field. Moved to 2 ward. Is exceedingly noisy again.
>
> Is still very noisy and restless at times and requires occasional doses of **sulphurnol (???)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section that you have indicated from this extract appears to read:

> Got out through window of **tuberch** section. And over 7 ward **airing court fence** onto the cricket field. Moved to 2 ward. Is exceedingly noisy again.
>
> Is still very noisy and restless at times and requires occasional doses of **sulphonal**.

---

The first word appears to be "tuberch", which is probably an abbreviation for "tuberculosis". This seems to be supported by the reference to the "airing court" which was an enclosed area where patients were able to exercise outdoors and were not uncommon features of TB hospitals.

**Sulphonal** was:

> "A substance employed as a hypnotic, produced by the union of mercaptan and acetone"

[Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, published 1913 by G. & C. Merriam Co](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sulphonal)

Comment: Thank you. The cause of death refers to tuberculosis so I am inclined to agree with your suggestions.

Comment: However, the word doesn’t look like “field” since this word appears later in the sentence. Could it be “court” fence?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was reading ahead while transcribing (always a bad habit).  Yes, it is "court" as per my note below the transcription!