# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

This is a continuation of

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes extract?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes - Extract 2](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes - Extract 3](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes - Extract 4](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)

  [image: Case notes extract 5]

> Has inflammation at most of night middle **???** and left **???** and little **???**.
>
> Still deluded and noisy and now sleeps well at night without **hypnoties (???)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section of the extract that you have indicated appears to read:

> Dec 14 Has inflammation at **root** of **right-middle fingernail** and left **ring** and little **fingernails**.
>
> [date & text not visible in image] ... sleeps well at night without **hypnotics**