# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

This is a continuation of:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)

[image: Extract 6]

> Admitted to ward 7 and put to bed in side room. Caution as to suicide. Is very often excited, terrified and noisy. Thinking she is going to be killed. Refuses food and has to be fed. **???** brandy **???** iii in XXIV (14) hours. Fed her rectum with **hepitonized (???)** milk.

I assume the first must be related to a medical measure again. I had not ever heard of feeding someone via their rectum before! **Hepitonize** is not a valid word so I wondered if it might be **pasteurized**.

Comment: No idea on the first part, but googling seems to confirm that "peptonized milk" was an established substance for feeding 'per rectum'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, after some investigation:

> ℞ brandy ℥iii in XXIV hours. Fed per rectum with peptonized milk.

[℞](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rx) designates a prescription
[℥](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%A5) is an apothecary symbol denoting 'ounce' so 3 ounces per 24h
Peptonized milk 'per rectum' was apparently a common method of nutrition for those unable or struggling to eat normally

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. I can't believe i wrote 14 instead of 24 either for XXIV!