# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about General appearance / Description of Bodily Symptoms

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

[image: Extract]

> Has a wild and terrified expression. A few stumps of teeth remain. Lips dry. Tongue **???** and dry. Pupils of medium size, equal, regular, react to light and to accommodation. **??? ??? ???**. Planter reflexes not obtained. Chest 28 ¼ in. Head 22 in. **???** 12 ¾ in. Ear to ear 10 ⅞ in. Ear 2 ⅝ in.

---

Related citations:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15697/8882)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text in this extract reads as follows:

> Has a wild and terrified expression. A few stumps of teeth remain. Lips dry. Tongue **furred** and dry. Pupils of medium size, equal, regular, react to light and to accommodation. **Kneejerk rather brisk**. **Plantar** reflexes not obtained. Chest 28 ¼ in. Head 22 in. **Ant<sup>r</sup> Post<sup>r</sup>** 12 ¾ in. Ear to ear 10 ⅞ in. Ear 2 ⅝ in.

---

*Ant<sup>r</sup>* is an abbreviation for "anterior"

Similarly, *Post<sup>r</sup>* is an abbreviation for "posterior"

Ant<sup>r</sup> Post<sup>r</sup> simply means "from front to back"

Comment: Thanks! I guess if you do a lot of documents of this nature you pick up on terms to look for.

Comment: "from front to back" - is this referring to her head do you think?

Comment: Given the context, I;d say so. [Craniometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craniometry) was still in vogue into the early 20th century.

Comment: Also, having done a fair bit of human bio-archaeology over the years I've picked up quite a lot of the 'jargon' used by anatomists and anthropologists!