# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about a suspicious mark / Diarrhoea

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

These are the last entries on page 2 of the case notes before the document continues with a final page in another volume.

[image: Extract]

> 2.3.17 P. back in 7 with Diarrhoea. Frequently complains after **???** when nothing is **???**.
>
> 7.3.17 Has a suspicious mark **??? ??? ???**.

I have assumed that the abbreviation **P.** means **Patient**.

*Please note that I think this is a different write to the other extracts due to the initials in the left column of the document.*

---

Related citations:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15697/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about General appearance / Description of Bodily Symptoms](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15701/8882)

Comment: I'm a bit pressed for time today, so this is incomplete. Perhaps someone else can work out the remaining words & post as an answer:

2.3.17 P. back in 7 with Diarrhoea. Frequently complains of having diarrhoea when nothing is wrong.

7.3.17 Has a suspicious rash ordered(?) ??? ??? scabies.

Comment: @sempaiscuba scabies would make sense because the next entry refers to the same. Thanks for help on this thus far.

Comment: I wonder if it is "Has a suspicious rash around ... ... scabies".

Comment: Anyone else able to suggest completion of this entry? Thank you.