# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patient "quotations"

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

My ancestor was reported to say the following statements:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

> "Don't **???** kill me"
>
> "Oh do **???** spare my life!"

At first I wondered if the word I can't decipher stood for **you all** but then the abbreviation would have been **y'all** and all I can see is **'??**.

---

Related citations:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15697/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about General appearance / Description of Bodily Symptoms](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15701/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about a suspicious mark / Diarrhoea](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15706/8882)

Comment: Probably 'ee (meaning "you") in both cases.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I saw this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_(pronoun) web page and I notice that it refers to **thee**. So I assume that **'ee** was abbreviation for that word. With **you** being the modern rendering. Correct?

Comment: Yes.  See my answer below, with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually probably ***'ee*** (meaning "you") in both cases.

This would be an attempt to transcribe the speech mannerisms of the patient.  In this case "*thee*" (for "you") in a regional dialect.

You can see many similar examples in books like, for example, [The Way to Penwellard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ugBZBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22don%27t%20%27ee%22&source=bl&ots=OSXDZBQwzr&sig=ACfU3U1e_Krf8T0fymAfeAi4cz-WIoEOAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiskIrZ6onkAhWtQxUIHevpB7I4ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22don't%20'ee%22&f=false) by Claire Collard.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I am nearly complete with this document. I have about 6 issues left (excluding the current outstanding one that you already commented on). I will ask one or two of those later on. Do you have a email address? I think it was you who wanted to see the original documents. I am happy to share them with you for your personal use.