# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about the patients health

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

With the exception of this currently open [question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15706/8882) (from the list below), there is one more deciphering issue on page 2 of 3 in these lunacy case notes of my ancestor.

[image: Extract]

> 11.8.16 Is much better now **???** fair health.

---

Related citations:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15697/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about General appearance / Description of Bodily Symptoms](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15701/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about a suspicious mark / Diarrhoea](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15706/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patient "quotations"](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15710/8882)

Comment: "**+ in** fair health" for "and in ...".

Comment: @sempaiscuba Ah - I see that now. I was convinced it was one word before! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry reads:

> 11.8.16 Is much better now + in fair health.

"**+ in** ..." is just and abbreviation for "and in ...".

---

Use of '+' for "and" used to be commonplace. Its use is now [discouraged](https://consumermedsafety.org/latest-fda-medication-alerts/item/460-ismps-list-of-error-prone-abbreviations-symbols-and-dose-designations) or banned in medical practice almost everywhere (along with many other terms which used to be commonly used - such as 'dram', to give another example)

Comment: Thank you. For clarity I have simply transcribed it as "and in".

Comment: Following modern recommended medical practice!  ;-)