# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about Unions and First Names

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

We are nearly complete with transcribing the lunacy case notes for my ancestor. I could not have done it without everyone's help and it has been interesting learning a few things along the way.

I have two extracts remaining on page 1 of 3. I thought that in this case I could include both in the same question.

At the top of the notes if makes reference to a **Union**.

[image: Extract 1]

Clearly it is **Salisbury** but there appears to be another letter at the end. At first thought I considered it was simply **C** for **Salisbury City**. But I really don't know. I am not even sure in what context **Union** is being used here.

In fact, seeing the image again here when editing the question, I don't think it is C because I can see Carter just below. They are not the same. I am now thinking that it is just a squiggle and the union is simply Salisbury. I am happy to cut this part of the question out if I am correct.

---

The final query for deciphering on page 1 has to do with a **first name**:

[image: Extract 2]

> **???** Maria. She is very restless, excited and noisy continually shouting and imploring me to spare her life. ...

I am confident that the surname is Maria (although come to think of it, Maria doesn't sound like a surname!).

Help appreciated in completing page 1.

---

Related citations:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15697/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about General appearance / Description of Bodily Symptoms](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15701/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about a suspicious mark / Diarrhoea](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15706/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patient "quotations"](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15710/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about the patients health](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15713/8882)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Union" in this case will bee the [Poor Law Union](http://www.workhouses.org.uk/England/UnionsEngland.shtml) under which the asylum was being run.

The boundaries of the Salisbury Poor Law Union (PLU) can be seen in this [1909 map of Wiltshire](http://visionofbritain.org.uk/maps/sheet/os_maps_1900/Wiltshire_1900).

---

In the second extract, the passage is:

> **Recent mania**. She is very restless, excited and noisy continually shouting and imploring me to spare her life.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of "Union". So I was barking up the wrong tree thinking it was a name for the second extract! Oops. Much appreciated.