# Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about products administered / surname

Tags: england, palaeography, 1910s, documents

Here are my remaining transcription queries on page 3 to complete the asylum case notes:

[image: Extract]

> 7.7.17 Has an attack of vomiting and is very weak. Has been put to bed in hospital. Milk **???**.
>
> 2.9.17 Could retain no food this **???**. Soduwater and milk given and **mustard (???) ??? ???** stomach this.

I did some research to come up with **Soduwater**. Looks like another term for **carbonated water**.

> 14.7.17 Reception Order 30th October 1912. Martha Scammell received 30th October 1912. Died 14th December 1917 (Signed) James **Turner (???)**. Clerk. 14

Help appreciated in completing page 3.

---

Related citations:

- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patients previous history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15681/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about nurses entry?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15686/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Paraldehyde](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15687/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15688/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about symptoms of inflammation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15689/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about administering Brandy and Milk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15697/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about General appearance / Description of Bodily Symptoms](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15701/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about a suspicious mark / Diarrhoea](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15706/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about patient "quotations"](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15710/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about the patients health](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15713/8882)
- [Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about Unions and First Names](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15715/8882)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of this extract is as follows:

> 7.7.17 Has an attack of vomiting and is very weak. Has been put to bed in hospital. Milk **diet**.
>
> 2.9.17 Could retain no food this **Evg** (?). **Sodawater** and milk given and mustard **leaf applied over** stomach + liver.

---

I suspect that 'Evg' is being used here as an abbreviation for "evening". Once again, '+' is being used for "and".

For an example of sodawater and milk being given to patients, have a look at the 1907 edition of [Mrs Beeton's Book of Household Management](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Mrs_Beeton%27s_Book_of_Household_Management.djvu/1513), p 1347.

Mustard leaf was often applied for topical pain relief.  If you search Google (or your preferred search engine) for the the phrase `"mustard leaf applied"` (including the quotes) you will find many examples in case notes & medical literature.

---

Finally, I concur with your reading of the surname as "Turner", making the last line:

> 14.7.17 Reception Order 30th October 1912. Martha Scammell received 30th October 1912. Died 14th December 1917 (Signed) James **Turner**. Clerk. 14th